Can "Place of interest" be used for personal preferences/interest?
According to what I've searched, "Place of interest" often describes tourist attractions, landmarks, museums, parks, historical sites, or any other location that people may find interesting or worth exploring.
So can I use "place of interest" to describe a place that I personally enjoy going to, such as my favorite coffee shop?
(As I also googled the phrase "my place of interest" and didn't get many hits)

A coffee shop is not a place of interest, unless it had become famous for some reason. Think of Katz an American deli in NYC which has become a tourist attraction after a famous scene starring Meg Ryan, was filmed there.

You can say "I'm particularly fond of this place (any building/shop) or spot (view)”

Not really. A place of interest implies something is famous or well known, or which is interesting for some specific reason, not just somewhere people like to go.

And to add to @BillyKerr’s comment, it is interesting to the general community, or at least to a segment. But anyway, not to only a single individual.

"My place of interest" would only really make sense if you owned a cathedral or monument or something. You could say "it's a place of interest for me", but that's maybe splitting the phrase "place of interest" into its two parts.
